# What is a semantic script?

Tags: semantics

Recently, there was a question about 'semantic roles', and someone explained them to me here.  It was great.  So, I was hoping someone may also know what "semantic scripts" are.  I've tried searching Google and some dictionary websites, but they aren't coming up with anything.  Actually, I am only able to find the term used in a theory of humor.  I need to have the term defined to understand that theory, though.  So, the context is poisoned.

Comment: I googled *semantic script* because I didn't know what it was, and used what I found for an answer. Now I think OP is looking for a definition relating to linguistics rather than humour theory, but frankly I don't think there is one with any significant currency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia [Theories of humor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theories_of_humor) ...

> The General Theory of Verbal Humor (GTVH) proposed by Victor Raskin and Salvatore Attardo in 1991 (an extension of the **semantic script theory of humour**, SSTH, which Raskin proposed in 1985) identifies a semantic model capable of expressing incongruities between semantic scripts in verbal humor; this has been seen as an important recent development in the theory of laughter.

[The core of the theory](http://www.pragmaticshumour.net/makingsenseofhumour/5.1modelsofcompetence.htm) is simply that humour involves juxtaposed incompatibilities. A "text" (joke) is funny if...

- the text is compatible, fully or in part, with two different scripts
- the two scripts with which the text is compatible are opposite.

...where "scripts" are *semantically comprehensible meanings.*

Comment: Sounds like 2 1/2 Men. :/

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, a semantic script is a collection of concepts that are related to a particular task or event.  These concepts may have causal relationships with each other with respect to that event.

Here's an example because that's stupidly abstract:

Suppose you have a text and someone says, "Yeah, I took a flight yesterday."  While a literal interpretation of that involves just the flight itself, we as readers understand a whole context and chain of events implied by that.  So we know that that person probably:

1. Bought a ticket
2. Went to an airport
3. Waited in a terminal
4. Boarded a plane
5. Ate something salty
6. Took a nap
7. Disembarked

Also, there bunch of optional or non-causal events and entities involved that we know about.  Like what?  A pilot, a plane, tickets, ears popping, etc.

The script encapsulates all those things and relates them *with respect to taking a flight*.

Source:  I'm a ph.d student in computational linguistics and I'm procrastinating writing my dissertation by answering a random question I stumbled upon on the internet.